# How to know the actual header sent by webclient in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I used webclient to surf a site with a proxy and I got no result. I use firefox to access the same site with the same proxy and I got result.

I want to know what sort of header webclient send and compare that with livehttp add on in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I want to see what's actually being sent and recevied over the wire with HTTP, I use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp)

Comment: that's what I actually use. +1 picked as answer too.